# StateMachineInterceptor missed after restoring state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

I've got problem with my state machine. After rerunnig my service, statemachine that restored is missing StateMachineInterceptor, that I added when was creating the statemachine instance for the first time.

Interceptor is important for me, because of some post processing after each transition, and listener looks not suitable for it (I need stateMachineInstance in default method)

All realated code located below:

```
public class StateMachineConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<S,E>{
@Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<S, E> config) throws Exception {
        config
            .withPersistence()
            .runtimePersister(stateMachinePersister);
        config
            .withConfiguration()
            .autoStartup(false)
            .listener(listener);
    }
```

StateMachineService config:

```
    @Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StateMachineServiceConfig {

    private final StateMachineFactory<S, E> factory;
    private final StateMachineRuntimePersister<S, E, String> stateMachinePersister;

    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<S, E> stateMachineService() {
        return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(factory, stateMachinePersister);
    }
}
```

My persister:

```
@Configuration
public class StateMachinePersistenceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public StateMachineRuntimePersister<S, E, String> stateMachinePersister(
            final JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository) {
        return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
    }
}
```

I'm also a bit confused because it uses only state_machine table, other were created once and had no changes.

Class for creating and restoring stateMachines:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class RelocationRequestsSSMService {

    private final StateMachineService<S, E> stateMachineService;
    private final MyInterceptor stateMachineInterceptor;

    public StateMachine<S, E> createStateMachine() {
        StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine = stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(UUID.randomUuid());
        stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().withRegion().addStateMachineInterceptor(stateMachineInterceptor);
        log.debug("Created ssm with id: " + stateMachine.getId());
        return stateMachine;
    }


    private StateMachine<S, E> getStateMachineBySsmId(String ssmId) {
        log.debug("Request ssm from persister with id: " + ssmId);
        StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine = stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(ssmId);
        log.debug("Get ssm from persister with id and uuid: " + stateMachine.getId() + " " + stateMachine.getUuid());
        return stateMachine;
    }
```

Maybe persister saves the statemachine instance incorrectly, so if I misconfigured it pls help

Thanks in advance!